# How to fix Django admin look?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

The admin of my Django application looks like shown below.

[image: Django admin]

Obviously, some stylesheets have been lost and/or corrupted.

Questions:

1. Which stylesheets are used to render the Django admin in the default way?
2. Where can I find them?

**Update 1 (10.06.2013 00:18 MSK):** Executing `manage.py collectstatic` results in the following output and didn't change the look of the admin.

```
D:\dev\history-site>C:\Python25\python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\bas
e.css'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\cha
ngelists.css'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\das
hboard.css'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\for
ms.css'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\ie.
css'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\log
in.css'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\rtl
.css'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\wid
gets.css'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\cha
ngelist-bg.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\cha
ngelist-bg_rtl.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\cho
oser-bg.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\cho
oser_stacked-bg.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\def
ault-bg-reverse.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\def
ault-bg.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\del
eted-overlay.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n-no.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n-unknown.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n-yes.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_addlink.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_alert.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_calendar.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_changelink.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_clock.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_deletelink.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_error.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_searchbox.png'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\ico
n_success.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\inl
ine-delete-8bit.png'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\inl
ine-delete.png'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\inl
ine-restore-8bit.png'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\inl
ine-restore.png'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\inl
ine-splitter-bg.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\nav
-bg-grabber.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\nav
-bg-reverse.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\nav
-bg-selected.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\nav
-bg.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\sel
ector-icons.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\sel
ector-search.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\sor
ting-icons.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\too
l-left.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\too
l-left_over.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\too
l-right.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\too
l-right_over.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\too
ltag-add.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\too
ltag-add_over.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\too
ltag-arrowright.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\too
ltag-arrowright_over.gif'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\gis
\move_vertex_off.png'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\img\gis
\move_vertex_on.png'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\acti
ons.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\acti
ons.min.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\cale
ndar.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\coll
apse.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\coll
apse.min.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\comp
ress.py'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\core
.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\getE
lementsBySelector.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\inli
nes.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\inli
nes.min.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\jque
ry.init.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\jque
ry.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\jque
ry.min.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\LICE
NSE-JQUERY.txt'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\prep
opulate.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\prep
opulate.min.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\Sele
ctBox.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\Sele
ctFilter2.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\time
parse.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\urli
fy.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\admi
n\DateTimeShortcuts.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\admi
n\ordering.js'
Copying 'C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\admi
n\RelatedObjectLookups.js'

72 static files copied.

D:\dev\history-site>
```

**Update 2 (10.06.2013 00:28):** Here's my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'history_site.views.home'),
    (r'^opinion/(\d+)$', 'history_site.views.opinion_details'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: How are you running it? From the test server that comes with Django, or through a dedicated webserver?

Comment: most likely your `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is not set. What is your django version?

Comment: The files are under `contrib/admin/static/admin/`, and Django (1.4 or later) expects them to be served under `<STATIC_URL>/admin/` where [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#static-url) is defined in your settings. Earlier versions (1.3 and before) used the [ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix) setting.

Comment: @Blair I run it using `C:\Python25\python manage.py runserver`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Admin's static files are missing. When you run Django with `DEBUG = True` it will serve static files automatically. In production you should make your webserver serve them (since they are *static* and serving them dynamically with Django is a waste of resources).

I'd suggest checking [this HOWTO](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/). Long story short:

1. Set `STATIC_URL` to whatever you like (default `/static/` is fine).
2. Set `STATIC_ROOT` to a directory, files from which will be served by your webserver at `STATIC_URL`. (That is, when browser requests `yourdomain.com/static/foo` the webserver should go to `STATIC_ROOT` and take `foo` from there)
3. Execute `./manage.py collectstatic` each time your static files are changed. It will collect all the files from your installed apps (`INSTALLED_APPS`) and copy them to `STATIC_ROOT`.

In case of Django admin, its static files will also be collected by `collectstatic` (since `admin` is just a normal application and it is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to use `collectstatic` and it actually copied 72 files into `/static/admin` directory (see my update 1 above). But the problem persists - the admin still looks the old way. Other items you mentioned seem to be correct (`STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`).

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Have you configured your production webserver to serve those files? Can you access `http://yourdomain.com/static/admin/css/base.css`?

Comment: When I enter `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css` I get a 404 error. In my update 2 above I posted the contents of my `urls.py` file. How do I need to change it in order for the static files to become available?

Comment: Wait, are you using Django's built-in webserver `./manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the built-in server.

Comment: Hm, it should serve them automatically. Even without those extra patterns in `urls.py`. What is the value of `DEBUG` in `settings.py`? What version of Django is it?

Comment: Note that I added Twitter Bootstrap styles to my Django application. Maybe they cause this trouble.

Comment: That's unlikely. Again, what version of Django are you using? Are you sure that `admin` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.4.0 (at least I see `VERSION = (1, 4, 0, 'final', 0)` in `C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django`). `'django.contrib.admin'` is listed in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I should admit, I'm out of ideas… Could you try with an empty project just to be sure that your Django installation is fine?

Comment: Django installation seems to be fine because earlier the admin worked and had the right look and feel.

Comment: The only major change was adding Twitter Bootstrap styles.

Comment: Ok, how exactly did you add them? And, well, try reverting this change…

Comment: I think the best way is to show you the code. Here it is - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11776689/2013_06_10_history-site.zip .

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko ok, your code has a number of issues, but the most important one is this: `STATIC_URL` should be `/static/`. You've put there an absolute URL and when Django sees an absolute URL it assumes that your static files are on a separate server and it won't seve them.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Other issues. First of all, reset `MEDIA_*` setting, you don't need them, [they are for user-uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/). In your case `history_site/history_site` is a directory with project-specific settings, don't create models, views, etc. there, make a separate app for this (go through [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) again to be sure).

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Don't point `STATIC_ROOT` to a directory _inside_ your project directory, it makes no sense. Read comment comment of this setting and never put files there yourself.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Please, next time follow advise you get. In my answer item #1 was setting `STATIC_ROOT` to the correct value. Doing just this in the code you've published solves the issue. And don't forget to change `SECRET_KEY` if you are planning to use this site in production as it is insecure now. Happy Django coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the staticfiles app in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  # ...
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```